# Critic question- all apps went

Tags: restore

After I install a packet with "apt-get install", console said me that some packets are unvalid so if you want to remove them write a command which I dont remember then I type yes.Now, nearly all apps are removed.How can I restore them easly?

history.log: https://justpaste.it/4l6er

term.log: https://justpaste.it/5dxl9

dpkg.log : https://justpaste.it/5z98p

command : -apt autoremove

---

edit 2:

console says some errors:

```
    Ayarlanıyor: fonts-tlwg-purisa (1:0.6.4-2) ...
dpkg: bağımlılık sorunları yüzünden acpi-support paketi yapılandırılamıyor:
 acpi-support şuna bağımlı: acpid (>= 1.0.4-1ubuntu4), ama:
  acpid paketi henüz yapılandırılmadı.

dpkg: acpi-support paketi işlenirken sorun yaşandı (--configure):
 bağımlılık sorunları - yapılandırılmadan bırakılıyor
Ayarlanıyor: libe-book-0.1-1:amd64 (0.1.3-1) ...
Apport raporu yazılmadı çünkü hata iletisi bu durumun bir önceki hatadan kaynaklanan bir hata olduğunu belirtiyor.
                                                                                                                  Ayarlanıyor: gir1.2-gmenu-3.0:amd64 (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Ayarlanıyor: gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0:amd64 (1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1) ...
```

---

```
Ayarlanıyor: acpid (1:2.0.28-1ubuntu1) ...
Job for acpid.service failed because of unavailable resources or another system error.
See "systemctl status acpid.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript acpid, action "start" failed.
● acpid.service - ACPI event daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/acpid.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: resources)

Oca 02 23:38:54 ahmet systemd[1]: acpid.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
Oca 02 23:38:54 ahmet systemd[1]: Failed to start ACPI event daemon.
Oca 02 23:38:55 ahmet systemd[1]: acpid.service: Got no socket.
Oca 02 23:38:55 ahmet systemd[1]: acpid.service: Failed to run 'start' task: Invalid argument
Oca 02 23:38:55 ahmet systemd[1]: acpid.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
Oca 02 23:38:55 ahmet systemd[1]: Failed to start ACPI event daemon.
Oca 02 23:38:55 ahmet systemd[1]: acpid.service: Got no socket.
Oca 02 23:38:55 ahmet systemd[1]: acpid.service: Failed to run 'start' task: Invalid argument
Oca 02 23:38:55 ahmet systemd[1]: acpid.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
Oca 02 23:38:55 ahmet systemd[1]: Failed to start ACPI event daemon.
dpkg: acpid paketi işlenirken sorun yaşandı (--configure):
 installed acpid package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Ayarlanıyor: gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4:amd64 (16.04.1+18.04.20171206-0ubuntu2) ...
Ayarlanıyor: fonts-sil-padauk (3.003-1) ...
```

---

start menu's search function doesnt work also computer tab doesnt show anything

---

edit 3:
camlyde
all programs started to crash then I ejected batery with panic.now, kubuntu transform to ubuntu

Comment: @user535733 I added all files

Comment: Thanks. That makes the problem clear enough to recommend an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/acpid stop

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo /etc/init.d/acpid start
```

Comment: can you explain this link i think it can help me :https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215215/how-to-restore-packages-removed-by-installing-a-program

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

This should reinstall the ubuntu-desktop metapackage, which depends on packages required for a normal desktop environment.

Comment: Warning for future readers: If the admin removes `ubuntu-desktop` for any reason (like uninstalling one of it's included applications), the entire desktop stack will become eligible for autoremoval again. Always read the entire list of proposed removals -- it's there to protect you. Tell apt 'No' if the list seems too large or if you don't understand the list.

Comment: console says some errors.I added them to edit

Comment: @user535733 can you explain this link to me? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215215/how-to-restore-packages-removed-by-installing-a-program